# jQuery append ignores inline CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code and it is not applying the CSS during output however if I copy the code into an html CSS works just fine but not when I execute this code:

```
var str_row;
str_row = '<div style="width:90%; float: left"> ';
str_row +='<div style="width:15%; float: left"> ';
str_row += '<div class="switch switch-square" ' ;
str_row += 'data-on-label="<i class='fui-check'></i>" ' ;
str_row += 'data-off-label="<i class='fui-cross'></i>" /> ' ;
str_row += '<input type="checkbox" checked></input> </div> ';
str_row += '</div> ';
str_row += "</div><div style='clear: right;'></div> ";

$("#row2").append(str_row);
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>###</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="my.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="row2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I need to know on getting the CSS class work under JQuery Append or any other function.

Thanks.

Comment: youre escaping quotes that don't need to be escaped and its forcing bad html to be rendered

Comment: You have invalid code as well, HTML chracters in attribute values must be escaped. Also `</input>` is not needed. Also why `var str_row; var str_row;` ? Can you post the HTML as well please?

Comment: I just updated the code. It has HTML now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm, do you mean something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfknoop/e8wwb/

```
str_row = '<div class="test1"> ';


 .test1 {
    width:90%; float: left
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but the class I'm using is from an external .css file that is linked in my html page and I'm assuming the external .css file class would work inside the .js code as in my original post. This is my external file [ <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" /> ] and the class in the code switch refers to this class. So I'm not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Hm ok, strangely this with background-colors seems to work :-) http://jsfiddle.net/cfknoop/e8wwb/1/

Comment: use the colons at the end of the floats i think will done this

Comment: yep it works if I hard-code but the css classes are too long to hard- code and that's why I have to reference them.

Comment: actually this has to work :-)

Comment: I placed the css before and get this output which is exactly that is supposed to do but still no display.. <div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="&lt;i class='fui-check'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" data-off-label="&lt;i class='fui-cross'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;"> <input type="checkbox" checked=""></div>. Here is the output file...  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4779304/issue.jpg

Comment: Have you removed the escapes? http://jsfiddle.net/cfknoop/e8wwb/2/

Comment: yep - it doesn't work. I'm using Flat UI and using the css but it just not working for this module.

Comment: All fixed guys . The Flat UI was throwing extra CSS in the view so copy the correct classes. It is working.